# Imported function can't get this.state

Tags: reactjs

I've got this simple code.
app.jsx

```
import { test } from './functions'
test()
```

and the functions.jsx

```
var test
test = () => {
    console.log(this.state)
}
export { test }
```

This gives me:
TypeError: _this is undefined

So I try binding it like this:

```
this.test = this.test.bind(this)
```

In my constructor in app.jsx, but the same error occurs.

Comment: When you call `this.test.bind(this)` you bind the `this` to the this in app.jsx. But there is also no `this` defined, because you call it outside of a function! `this` is only defined in functions!

Comment: Could you submit that as a solution so I can try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind this to an arrow function.

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function
>   expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own
>   this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always
>   anonymous.

This should work:

```
const test = function() {
    console.log(this.state)
}
export { test }
```

call like this:

```
// react comp
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.test = test.bind(this)
  this.test();
```

example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/z6yynxoj1p

Comment: Though so too, but this gave me a slightly different error: TypeError: this is undefined

Comment: you'll still have to bind `this` to the above.. did you?

Comment: Yup, still have this.test = this.test.bind(this) in my constructor in app.jsx.

Comment: I think you are binding the wrong thing - should be this.test = test.bind(this)

Comment: see my working codesandbox example - you should be able to work it out from there

Comment: Tried your codesandbox example, and it does work.
However, I'm getting two console.logs and the following error:
The above error occurred in the <App> component:
    in App

TypeError: this is undefined

So it works...but the error prevents other elements from rendering.

Comment: There is no error - the undefined value printed out is because test() does not return a value. The only component being rendered is <div>hello</div> which shows up fine.

Comment: It was a problem on my project. Had another call for test function that was causing the error to appear again. Your solution worked. Accepted as the answer.